# Editable table react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to target a specific row to edit on my table in React.

My code looks something like this...

```
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState({ kind: { str: '', row: '' }});

const onChange = e => {
  setRowData({...rowData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }}
}

arr.map((ele, index) => (
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='kind' value={kind.str} row={index} onChange={e => onChange(e)}></td>
  </tr>
))
```

I didn't write all my code but I think that should be sufficient enough for an answer.
Basically I press a button `edit` that makes the row editable. When I press this button actually all rows and columns become editable which is not what I want but regardless of this outcome - I go to update the table and only that one input gets updated, unfortunately I get this error

```
A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component
```

After reading the error I then decided to change my `onChange` function to this...

```
const onChange = e => {
  setRowData({...rowData, [e.target.name]: { str: e.target.value, row: e.target.getAttribute('row')}}
}
```

the above solves the issue from making my `controlled` component becoming `uncontrolled` however all the input fields on each row that match the `kind` name get updated which is not the desired functionality I want.

How can I solve this issue. Eventually what I want is an editable table that the user can update a single row and update the database with the data they input.

The `arr` variable I am using is actually named `files`.

I have another component which gets all my files from my database and sets it to the files variable

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFiles = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/files/all', {
        method: 'GET',
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setFiles(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchFiles();
  }, []);
```

I then pass in as props files to my Items component which is where the code that I wrote for my question lives in.

Most of the code is here...

ShowList component

```
const ShowList = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [filesPerPage, setFilesPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [yourUploads, setYourUploads] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFiles = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/files/all', {
        method: 'GET',
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setFiles(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchFiles();
  }, []);

  const indexOfLastPage = currentPage * filesPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPage = indexOfLastPage - filesPerPage;
  const currentFiles = files.slice(indexOfFirstPage, indexOfLastPage);

  const paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='container'>
        <h3 className='text-center'>
          {yourUploads ? 'Your uploads' : 'All uploads'}
        </h3>

        <div className='d-flex dropdown'>
          <button
            className='btn mb-3 mr-3'
            type='button'
            id='dropdownMenuButton'
            data-toggle='dropdown'
            aria-haspopup='true'
            aria-expanded='false'
          >
            Pages per row {filesPerPage}
          </button>
          <div className='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
            <button
              className='dropdown-item'
              onClick={() => setFilesPerPage(5)}
            >
              5
            </button>
            <button
              className='dropdown-item'
              onClick={() => setFilesPerPage(10)}
            >
              10
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className='dropdown'>
            <button
              className='btn mb-3'
              type='button'
              id='dropdownUploadsButton'
              data-toggle='dropdown'
              aria-haspopup='true'
              aria-expanded='false'
            >
              {yourUploads ? 'your uploads' : 'all uploads'}
            </button>
            <div
              className='dropdown-menu'
              aria-labelledby='dropdownUploadButton'
            >
              <button
                className='dropdown-item'
                onClick={() => setYourUploads(true)}
              >
                your uploads
              </button>
              <button
                className='dropdown-item'
                onClick={() => setYourUploads(false)}
              >
                all uploads
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <table id='myTable' className='table table-striped w-100'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Title</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Kind</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Size</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Strength</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Combinations</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Favors</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Stock</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Carousel</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Owner</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Edit</small>
              </th>
              <th scope='col'>
                <small>Delete</small>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <Items
            files={currentFiles}
            loading={loading}
            yourUploads={yourUploads}
          />
        </table>

        <Pagination
          filesPerPage={filesPerPage}
          totalFiles={files.length}
          paginate={paginate}
        />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Items component

```
const Items = ({ files, loading, yourUploads }) => {
  const [myUploads, setMyUploads] = useState([]);
  const [editable, setEditable] = useState(false);
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState({
    kind: { str: '', row: '' },
  });

  const { kind } = rowData;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMyUploads = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/files/all/mine', {
        method: 'GET',
      });

      const data = await res.json();

      setMyUploads(data);
    };

    fetchMyUploads();
  }, [files]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setRowData({ ...rowData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e, file_id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!editable) {
      setEditable(!editable);
    } else {
      await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/files/${file_id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(rowData),
      });

      setEditable(!editable);
    }
  };

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>loading...</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    );
  }

  const list = yourUploads
    ? myUploads.map((file) => (
        <tr key={file._id}>
          <td>
            <small>{file.title}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.kind}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.size}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.strength}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.combinations}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.favors}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small
              className={file.availability ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger'}
            >
              {file.availability ? 'in stock' : 'out of stock'}
            </small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.isCarousel ? 'carousel' : 'not caorousel'}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.owner}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button className='btn btn-dark'>
              <small>edit</small>
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button className='btn btn-danger'>
              <small>delete</small>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))
    : files.map((file, index) => (
        <tr key={file._id}>
          <td>
            <small>{file.title}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>
              {editable ? (
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='kind'
                  value={kind.str}
                  row={index}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                />
              ) : (
                file.kind
              )}
            </small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.size}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.strength}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.combinations}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.favors}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small
              className={file.availability ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger'}
            >
              {file.availability ? 'in stock' : 'out of stock'}
            </small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.isCarousel ? 'carousel' : 'not carousel'}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <small>{file.owner}</small>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className='btn btn-dark'
              onClick={(e) => onSubmit(e, file._id)}
            >
              <small>{editable ? 'save' : 'edit'}</small>
            </button>
          </td>

          <td>
            <button className='btn btn-danger'>
              <small>delete</small>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ));

  return <tbody>{list}</tbody>;
};
```

Comment: I don't see where you used onChange method.

Comment: If you're not doing this for learning purpose, you can use libraries like [react ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid) which will more elegant and battle tested.

Comment: I am doing it for learning purposes and I left out the onChange={(e) = onChange(e)} in my input by mistake but it is there in my code. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually comes up when you pass null or undefined to the input value prop. If value prop is empty, then react thinks it became uncontrolled component.
So you need to fix the error here.

```
arr.map((ele, index) => (
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='kind' value={kind.str} row={index} onChange={e => onChange(e)}></td>
  </tr>
))
```

Change value={kind.str} to value={rowData.kind.str}

Comment: I have already destructured doing the following `const {kind} = rowData` Also just incase I tried it but still the same error. I know the issue is occurring because of the `rowData.kind.row` When I include as I did above in my question (the second version I made of my `onChange`) the issue goes away but then each row where I have the input field for kind gets updated if I were to just updated one row which I don't want

Comment: That's a natural behavior. Because you have multiple rows, you need to have rowData as an array, not a single object. I wanted to ask you to share the arr variable.

Comment: The `arr` is actually just a `files` that I brought into my component as props. It is an array of objects. Something like `[{kind: 'somekind', size: 'somesize'}, {}, {}, ...]` and so on.

Comment: I basically am able to get the desired functionality and am able to update the correct rows and fields but the error keeps popping up. I also just tried putting row as a field in the rowData and all of a sudden i was able to change the text in the input kind field without changing the other input kind fields in the other rows. I'm not sure how this actually ended up working but it does with the issue of row becoming uncontrolled

Comment: Is arr a static or dynamic value? In other words, arr is also a state or props variable?

Comment: dynamic. It can change based on if a user were to upload/edit/delete a file

Comment: I do `const Items = ({ files }) => {}` I'm not including the code the component actually has but that is how I start my function bringing in my files which is the arr that I have. I just wrote arr to make it clear that it is an array in my question

Comment: I need to see how arr is used, otherwise, it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my question to include my code. It starts from `ShowList component` and onwards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering my question. I was able to figure it out by splitting my components. So from my `Items` I render an Item component that renders the item and an `Edit` component that brings props in for that row only. By doing this I was able to eliminate the need for a `row` field which therefore gets rid of my error. React knows which row I am editing.